# How to change html azure mobile service as a PHP script?

Tags: php, azure, azure-mobile-services

Anyway to change html type of azure mobile service to be run as a PHP script?

I want to create a page that can update the azure mobile service database when the page is called.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you're talking about the "default" page (the one which is shown when you browse to https://your-service.azure-mobile.net) - that's a static page to show that the service is running and cannot be changed.

One possibility to create dynamic pages would be to create a [custom API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn303368.aspx) for your service, but currently only JavaScript (node.js) is supported.